# Munin master not fetching data from external Munin-node

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, monitoring, network-monitoring, munin

I am trying to make my munin master fetch data from another external munin-node. But I seems to be running into problems.  The Munin master exist at 10.0.0.4, while the external node is at 10.0.0.1. I am trying to make 10.0.0.4 fetch the data from 10.0.0.1.

I believe I have set up the configuration correctly:

Edited /etc/munin/munin.conf on the munin_master to make it fetch data from 10.0.0.1.

```
[muninServer.vm] 
address 10.0.0.1 
use_node_name yes
```

Restarted Munin and apache on munin_master.

```
/etc/init.d/munin-node restart
* Stopping Munin-Node    [ OK ]
 * Starting Munin-Node     [ OK ]
```

Also restarted apache2 on munin_master

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

On the external munin-node edited /etc/munin/munin-node.conf, to allow the munin_master to collect the files from the external munin-node.

```
allow ^10\.0\.0\.4$
```

Also restarted munin.

```
/etc/munin# /etc/init.d/munin-node restart
 * Stopping Munin-Node             [ OK ]
 * Starting Munin-Node               [ OK ]
```

This seems to work fine for munin_master. However, when Munin master tries to establish a new connection with 10.0.0.1  on port 4949(by sending a SYN bit). The external node refuses the connection and responds with a reset bit. Since the external node is specified to accept this connection, I don’t see why this happens.

My local firewall at 10.0.0.1 accept all traffic in by default. So this cannot be the reason:

```
iptables -L Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT) target     prot opt source     destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT) target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT) target     prot opt source               destination
```

Might be important to note that using: telnet 127.0.0.1 4949 on the external node works fine, while using telnet 10.0.0.1 4949 on the munin_master is being refused.

Trying to find out if the port is listening on the external node:

```
lsof | grep TCP | grep LISTEN
munin-nod  4669             root    5u     IPv4            2095805      0t0        TCP localhost:munin (LISTEN)

netstat -tulpn
Proto  Recv-Q      Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0             0             127.0.0.1:4949          0.0.0.0:*                LISTEN      4669/perl
```

The content on the information in  munin-node.conf on the external node.

```
log_level 4
log_file /var/log/munin/munin-node.log
pid_file /var/run/munin/munin-node.pid
background 1
setsid 1
user root
group root

ignore_file [\#~]$
ignore_file DEADJOE$
ignore_file \.bak$
ignore_file %$
ignore_file \.dpkg-(tmp|new|old|dist)$
ignore_file \.rpm(save|new)$
ignore_file \.pod$

allow ^127\.0\.0\.1$
allow ^::1$
allow ::ffff:158.36.119.179
allow ^10\.0\.0\.4$
allow ^128\.39\.74\.58$

host 127.0.0.1
host ::ffff:158.36.119.179

port 4949
```

Any suggestion to how to fix this problem would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

On node 10.0.0.1, type `$ tail -f /var/log/munin/munin-node.log`
then press enter a couple of times to clear the screen. This is only for you to see the new results.

In another window, go to node 10.0.0.4, and type 
`$ telnet 10.0.0.1 4949` and see if the answer to your conundrum is in one of the windows.